# OpenShift free account and custom ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, openshift

Does Openshift free account allows application with self-signed certificate and will I be able to use https://....  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift Online does not currently support custom SSL certificates on the free account.  You would have to upgrade to at least the Bronze account to use a custom SSL certificate.

Self-signed SSL certificates are supported on the paid tiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using cloudflare, they provide free wildcard certificates to all account levels.

All my sites at SSL'd via them. Added bonuses would be a free cdn and free security.

Comment: How exactly do you configure your openshift to use cloudflare ssl certificates?

Comment: You need to setup cloudflare as your name server first, you will then add a cname record under openshift and cloudflare, from then on you can use their free ssl on your CNAMED'd domain.

As long as cloudflare is managing the domains you can use any of its rules, addons and services for it including the free ssl.

Comment: You're right, I was having a cache problem. I tested in other machines and it worked. Here is a post with a more detailed description of what I've done. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95080/configure-3-domains-in-cloudflare-with-2-redirecting-to-the-first-one-for-a-wo/